# Webpack + Gulp Cannot Get Url and return 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp, react-router

I have a problem with Gulp + Webpack on small React project.
On request to undefined url I need gulp to return index.html
That's because I use React + React router dom and on refresh or manually input URL my app get broken because the first request is send to gulp-connect server and he don't know what to send me when he don't find that route

gulpfile.js:

```
 gulp.task('connect', function () {
  var port = 9000;
  var serverConfiguration = {
    root: [
      paths.dest.folder,
      paths.dest.folder + '/src'
    ],
    base: 'http://localhost',
    port: port,
    livereload: true,
    fallback:'./index.html'
  };

  var server = connect.server(serverConfiguration);

  open('http://localhost:' + port);

  return server;
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/, 
              loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
            }
          ]
    },

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },

    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: {
        index:'./index.html'
      },
      hot: true
    }};
```

So I need when i go to the unknown url gulp to send index.html

I set up the fallback of the connect module but it give me an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

So where i'm wrong and what i don't do into the right way.
I have devServer.historyApiFallback set to true or to './index.html' in webpack config file and the fallback on gulp-connect but it still give me this error. Someone to know what is wrong here?

Comment: How do you start your server ?

Comment: with gulp, that's why i post gulp connect task

Comment: Coz, since you have `weback-devServer` config, i was wondering how you are starting both the servers and using them..

Comment: i used webpack dev server but after that i switched to gulp only, and the interesting is that route "/" is resolved, route "/:param" or "/static" are also resolved and don't crash on refresh, but route "/static/static" or "/static/:param" crushes and console give me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <